# expo image are very slow and not good performance but why

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a lot of storys maybe 20-30. And each story has an Image. If I scroll the images are very slow and its lag (hang out). I used this: https://dev.to/dmitryame/implementing-fast-image-for-react-native-expo-apps-1dn3

but If I add a new Story (Image) to the state , then the new Image is not showing.

What you use to read fast images which good performance?

small snippet:

```
...
  const [storys, setStorys] = useState(route.params.storys || []);
...

        <ScrollView>
          <ScrollView
            horizontal={true}
            contentContainerStyle={{height: 100, marginLeft: 12}}
            scrollEventThrottle={50}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            decelerationRate="normal"
          >
          {
            storys.length > 0 
            ?
              storys.map((el, i) => {
                return (
                  <TouchableOpacity key={`index-${i}`} style={{padding: 0, marginRight: 12, borderWidth: 2, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', borderRadius: 100, borderColor: 'red', height: 88, width: 88}}>
                    
                    <Image source={{uri: `http://xx.xxxx.xx:3000/uploads/${el.source}`}} style={{height: 55, width: 55, borderRadius: 500}} />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                )
              })
            :
            <Text>Es sind zurzeit keine Storys vorhanden.</Text>
          }
          </ScrollView>
        </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Install these first,

```
npm i react-native-expo-image-cache
```

then

```
npm i expo-blur
```

then import like this..

```
import { Image } from "react-native-expo-image-cache";
```

Use it like this..

```
<Image 
  style={{height: 55, width: 55, borderRadius: 500}} 
  uri={`http://xx.xxxx.xx:3000/uploads/${el.source}`}
  preview={{ uri: `http://xx.xxxx.xx:3000/uploads/${el.source}` }}  // Here if you have a preview of the image then place it here...
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it download very slow, in 30sec I see white backgrounds because the images are not loaded yet